# DateTime Parse ANSI C timestamp

Tags: c#, datetime, ansi-c

I am trying to parse Date/Time formats in HTTP/1.1 headers as specified in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3)

How do I parse an ANSI C timestamp in C#?
The closest I get is:

```
string dateFormat = "ddd MMM d HH':'mm':'ss yyyy";
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Jan  2 15:04:05 2006", dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The problem lies in "d" which does not accept a leading space in case it is a single digit date. And "dd" requires a leading 0 instead.

Is there any easy way around, or maybe a library that already handles the three allowed date/time formats in HTTP/1.1?

Comment: DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Jan  2 15:04:05 2006".Replace("  "," ") ......   would get rid of the extra leading space

Comment: @PaulF True. I just noticed DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite which would have a similar result. It would allow "broken" ANSI C timestamps with only 23 chars, but I don't see how that could cause any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`DateTime.TryParseExact` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes `string[]` as a format parameter with [`AllowInnerWhite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) style?

```
string s = "Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT";
DateTime dt;
var formats = new[] 
{
    "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'",
    "dddd, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'",
    "ddd MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy"
};
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite, out dt))
{
    //
}
```